# Classes in $H^3(G; \mathbb{Z})$ that restrict to zero on abelian subgroups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Is it possible to have a nonzero class in $H^3(G; \mathbb{Z})$ that restricts to zero in $H^3(A; \mathbb{Z})$ for every abelian subgroup $A \subset G$? If so, what is a simple example?

Comment: What motivates this question?

Comment: @ChrisGerig: a project on Picard groups of ring spectra. This is exactly the type of result we'd need to calculate a certain Picard group.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about in general, but what you're after is tied in to (integral) **Essential Cohomology** $Ess_\mathbb{Z}(G)$, as follows:

Let $G$ be a finite group. An element $x\in H^*(G)$ is called *essential* if it has trivial restriction to all proper subgroups of $G$; the set of such elements make up the essential ideal $Ess_\mathbb{Z}(G)$. If $G$ is not a $p$-group, then this essential ideal is 0. Thus the main focus has been on mod-$p$ cohomology, especially when it's an easier ring to work under. But some stuff can be said for $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients. For an example, here is a computation I did a long time ago:

Take $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, so that $H^*(G,\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta,\mu]/(2\alpha,2\beta,\alpha\beta^2+\alpha^2\beta-\mu^2)$ where $|\alpha|=|\beta|=2$ and $|\mu|=3$. Then $\text{res}^G_{\mathbb{Z}_2\times 1}\alpha=\text{res}^G_{1\times \mathbb{Z}_2}\beta=\eta$ and $\text{res}^G_{\mathbb{Z}_2\times 1}\beta=\text{res}^G_{1\times \mathbb{Z}_2}\alpha=0$, where $H^*(\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}[\eta]/(2\eta)$ with $|\eta|=2$.  For the final maximal subgroup $M=\lbrace (0,0),(1,1)\rbrace$ we have $\text{res}^G_M\alpha=\eta$ and $\text{res}^G_M\beta=\eta$, so $\text{res}^G_M\alpha\beta=\eta^2$ and $\text{res}^G_M(\alpha+\beta)=0$.
Now $\mu$ must restrict to a $3$-dimensional element on the maximal subgroups, which it cannot because the rings are generated by a $2$-dimensional element $\eta$.  Thus $Ess_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2)=(\mu)$.

Comment: Note that I'm cheating with the example I gave, because $H^\text{odd}$ is zero for cyclic groups.

Comment: A detailed description of essential cohomology for elementary abelian p-groups can be found in: F. Altunbulak Aksu and D.J. Green, JPAA 213 (2009) 2238-2243.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt, unfortunately that's only for mod-p cohomology. But perhaps the Bockstein homomorphism is nontrivial in this case, which will produce essential elements with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that the $\mathbb{Z}$ case would rule out examples such as these; in your terminology I'd like for the essential cohomology $H^3$ to be zero for a nonabelian $p$-group.

Comment: I wrote up computations for all p-groups which contain an index-p cyclic subgroup; it's on my website. Perhaps you can use them (pass from $\mathbb{Z}_p$-coefficients to $\mathbb{Z}$ via Bockstein) to find your desired integral elements (they'll have to come from degree 2 elements in mod-p cohomology for the generalized quaternions or split-metacyclic groups). Anyway, now that you're here at Berkeley with me, we can meet sometime and chat further! (and recruit Qiaochu to use his secret category theory powers)

Comment: @ChrisGerig: thanks. I'll have a look, and yes, it'd be nice to chat further around Berkeley sometime.